# compute coherence in python

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I'm learning cross-spectrum and coherence. From what I understand, coherence is like the analogue of correlation in that you normalize the cross-spectrum by the product of individual power spectrum:

[image: wikipedia equation]

Here is my current python implementation

```
import numpy

def crossSpectrum(x,y):

    #-------------------Remove mean-------------------
    xp=x-numpy.mean(x)
    yp=y-numpy.mean(y)
    n=len(x)

    # Do FFT
    cfx=numpy.fft.fft(xp)/n
    cfy=numpy.fft.fft(yp)/n
    freq=numpy.fft.fftfreq(n)

    # Get cross spectrum
    cross=cfx.conj()*cfy

    return cross,freq


#-------------Main---------------------------------
if __name__=='__main__':

    x=numpy.linspace(-250,250,500)
    noise=numpy.random.random(len(x))
    y=10*numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x/10.)+5*numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x/5.)+\
            2*numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x/20.)+10
    y+=noise*10
    y2=5*numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x/10.)+5+noise*50

    p11,freq=crossSpectrum(y,y)
    p22,freq=crossSpectrum(y2,y2)
    p12,freq=crossSpectrum(y,y2)

    # coherence
    coh=numpy.abs(p12)**2/p11.real/p22.real
    print coh
```

And my computed coherence is an array of 1s. What am I doing wrong?

Also, sometimes the coherence plot has downward pointing spikes (like the output of `scipy.signal.coherence`, in other places that are pointing upward (e.g. [here](http://www2.ocean.washington.edu/flowmow/processing/currents/coh/billtest/cohtest.html)). I'm bit confused by the interpretation of coherence, shouldn't a larger coherence implies covariability between the 2 timeseries at that frequency?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You should have been using the welch method. As an example attached code similar to yours (with some simplifications) with expected results.

```
import numpy 
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, figure, ylim, xlabel, ylabel
def crossSpectrum(x, y, nperseg=1000):

#-------------------Remove mean-------------------
cross = numpy.zeros(nperseg, dtype='complex128')
for ind in range(x.size / nperseg):

    xp = x[ind * nperseg: (ind + 1)*nperseg] 
    yp = y[ind * nperseg: (ind + 1)*nperseg] 
    xp = xp - numpy.mean(xp)
    yp = yp - numpy.mean(xp)

    # Do FFT
    cfx = numpy.fft.fft(xp)
    cfy = numpy.fft.fft(yp)

    # Get cross spectrum
    cross += cfx.conj()*cfy
freq=numpy.fft.fftfreq(nperseg)
return cross,freq

#-------------Main---------------------------------
if __name__=='__main__':

x=numpy.linspace(-2500,2500,50000)
noise=numpy.random.random(len(x))
y=10*numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x)
y2=5*numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x)+5+noise*50

p11,freq=crossSpectrum(y,y)
p22,freq=crossSpectrum(y2,y2)
p12,freq=crossSpectrum(y,y2)

# coherence
coh=numpy.abs(p12)**2/p11.real/p22.real
plot(freq[freq > 0], coh[freq > 0])
xlabel('Normalized frequency')
ylabel('Coherence')
```

and visualization
[image]